# Will referring to a single ClientBundle class from multiple UiBinders cost anything?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a single ClientBundle with css resources that are needed throughout the application - default background colors, common layout patterns, etc.

A stated [design goal](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#ClientBundle_Goals) from GWT is that there be "no penalty for having multiple ClientBundle resource functions refer to the same content."  Do I have to do anything to avoid penalties and help ClientBundle realize this goal?

A naive approach would be to just add

```
<ui:with field="appWideResources"
    type='com.activegrade.client.resources.appwide.AppWideResources' />
```

at the top of every UiBinder file.  But, in my 22 jillion UiBinder files, will this create 22 jillion instances of AppWideResources, each with different and redundant obfuscations, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it that way or via the `@UiFactory` method, and neither would cost you anything additional. GWT will only instantiate a resource set once and share that single instantiation with every file that references that set.

"...each time you call `GWT.create()` (which a `ui:with` will do) it will instantiate a new object, but all resources in the `ClientBundle` are initialized as static fields, so each instance is only a very lightweight "proxy" to those static fields; and the GWT compiler will optimize it out in the end, (almost) as if you had a singleton instance." (Thomas Broyer)

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for! Thanks!

Comment: This is not exactly true, but it doesn't change the conclusions: each time you call `GWT.create()` (which a `ui:with` will do) it will instantiate a new object, but all resources in the `ClientBundle` are initialized as static fields, so each instance is only a very lightweight "proxy" to those static fields; and the GWT compiler will optimize it out in the end, (almost) as if you had a singleton instance.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Thanks for the clarification- that is what I meant, I guess my execution just wasn't as clear as yours. I'll update my answer to include your notes.